# Unable to obtain SQL query for column "format"

Tags: php, mysql

I can't seem to perform the proper selections from mySQL data.

```
$sort = $_GET['sort'];
// ...
$sql = "SELECT id, title, genre, format, year FROM dvd WHERE format LIKE '$sort%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql, $link);

<ul class="grid">
<?php
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
    { ?>
        ...
where $sort = 'dvd'
```

However, when i tried to do it manually,

`SELECT id, title, genre, format, year FROM dvd WHERE format LIKE 'dvd'`

i was able to obtain results using phpmyadmin -> mySQL -> SQL.

Why is it that i won't be able to get data whenever i choose format?

I tried this for other columns such as genre and title and i was able to get the result that i want. The columns were all structured to be the same VARCHAR and same settings

Comment: You forget the wildcard % in your manual query.

Comment: So `$sql = "SELECT id, title, genre, year FROM dvd WHERE format LIKE '$sort%'";` does work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the word "format" might be a keyword which is conflicting... change the column name "format" to something else... It will work...

Comment: Format is not a reserved word.

Comment: right, format is a function.. you can try to put the column name between these characters: ` if you don't want to change the names now..

Comment: @Wesley van Opdorp it's not a keyword but it's a function.. here is the link to mysql manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_format

Comment: what I mean abot by using these characters: ` was to write your query like this: http://codepad.org/a697Gl7f

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
"SELECT id, title, genre, format, year FROM dvd WHERE format LIKE '". $sort ."%'";
```

dont forget that $sort variable comes from $_GET and it must be secured

Answer (score 0):

Ask your database, not strangers who have no idea what's up with your database.

run your query this way

```
$sort = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sort']);
$sql = "SELECT id, title, genre, format, year FROM dvd WHERE format LIKE '$sort%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $link) or trigger_error(mysql_error()." in ".$sql);
```

and see what it says.